# How to derive camera orientation in Python from look_from vector and Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Python project where I'm trying to determine the orientation of a camera in a 3D space. I have the camera's position represented as a look_from vector and the Cartesian coordinates (x, y) of the target point the camera is looking at. However, I'm a bit stuck on how to calculate the camera's orientation from these parameters.

Could someone please guide me through the process or provide a Python implementation to derive the camera's orientation from the look_from vector and the target coordinates? Any explanations or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds more like a math question than a programming questions.

Comment: Ummmm. Should i delete the question or change the tag?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)